In golden layout structure adding a type 'column' to parent 'row', when the all the stacks in type column in closed, the row parent shows undefined
I have a Golden Layout config initialized in a constructor. I have added a type 'column' inside id, main on a button click().
constructor() {
   this.stackcounter = 0
   const cf = { content:[{
            type: 'row',
            id: 'main',
            content: [{
                type: 'column',
                id: 'left'
                content: [{
                    type: 'row',
                    id: 'top'
                },
                {
                    type: 'row',
                    id: 'table',
                    height: 30,  
                }]
            }]
           }]}

   this.layout = new GoldenLayout(cf, '#layout')
}

click(item) {
    if(this.stackcounter == 0) {
       this.layout.root.getItemsById('main')[0].addChild({id: 'right', type: 'column'})
    }
    this.layout.root.getItemsById('right')[0].addChild({id: 'stack', type: 'stack', content: item})
    this.stackcounter++

}


This works for the first time, but when all the stack is closed along with the column 'right', this.layout.root.getItemsById('main')[0] this becomes undefined and I cannot add the column 'right' again.
Even if I tried to add child using this.layout.root.getItemsById('left')[0].parent.addChild() it shows root cannot have multiple child.
